# VS Code: Extract interface in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code and I can't figure out if it's possible to take a class and extract an interface from it.  When I google how to do this, I only find extensions for TypeScript, but I want to do this in C#.

Can VS Code extract interfaces?  Knowing the shortcut would be nice for others, but I'm using a different keymap, so I'd like to know how to do this from the menu.

Comment: In 99.99% sure that there is no such feature for C# in VS Code.

Comment: Yes, there is no feature in VS to extract interface out of a class. A little bit of text processing will solve your problem. You can take all the public methods and properties of that class and it in interface. That is all required.

Comment: @NileshShinde that's so odd that people put time into this feature for TypeScript but not C#... but thanks for the info.

Comment: Just use Visual Studio, mate.

Answer (score 17):

You may try this,

Move your cursor on the class_name that you want to extract interface. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (period)
Then choose *"Extract Interface"* this will generate a code above the class that you want to be extracted.
Then move your cursor the interface class_name <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (period) again, then choose *"Move type to the"* auto-generated class name then that's it.

Hope this will help you guys and for future reference.

**PS:** Found out that this is only applicable to Visual Studio IDE

Comment: It only gives me an option to "Extract Base Class...", not sure why I don't have Extract Interface as an option :-(

Comment: The only actions that show up for me are "Generate constructor '[...]'" and "Add 'DebuggerDisplay attribute".

Comment: Doesnt work - extract interface not an option

Comment: This is an option in "Visual Studio", not in "Visual Studio Code"

Comment: For now it is not possible if you are using c# dev kit https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/6430

Answer (score 7):

Not really sure if this feature was already there or got implemented afterwards, but I found this:

First, extract the interface as usual

[image: Extract interface]

Then you get to do this on your methods:

[image: Extract signature]

Note that it doesn't add necessary `using`s but uses `namespace`s instead. You can do the clean up as you like.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Still looking for an extension that will do it a bit more simply.

Answer (score 1):

I find this kind of refactoring easier with Visual Studio than with Vscode. My solution is to have both IDE's installed and switch back and forth as needed. Just make sure to close the solution or folder in the one you're not using to avoid the annoying "your code was changed externally" dialog.

In Visual Studio, right click on your class, select Quick Actions > Extract Interface. Then switch back to Vscode, and you're good to go.

Comment: Wow. This sounds really inconvenient, but I'm glad that there is a way of pulling it off.