# VSCdoe pull 'method()' up to interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I remember in an implementation class there was an option `pull 'method' up to interface` in context menu when put cursor on method name and press `cmd+.` like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57670070/17562147), but since some version upgrade I can no longer find this.

Is there any setting for this?

[image]

- OS: macOS Monterey 12.5.1 on M1 Pro
- VSCode: 1.71.1

Comment: does this method belong to a class that implements an interface?

Comment: @Piglet yes! the class implements an interface.